# Translating an RSA decrypt function from Golang to Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, go, rsa

I need an equivalent of this golang function in Python :

```
func RsaDecrypt(ciphertext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    block, _ := pem.Decode(privateKey)
    if block == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("private key error!")
    }
    priv, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return rsa.DecryptPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, priv, ciphertext)
}
```

I'm a python developer, and do not understand how this works. I have created this function, but it is not the same:

```
import rsa

with open("rsa.key") as f:
    priv_key_pkcs1 = f.read()

priv_key = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(priv_key_pkcs1)
line = '''
Lyzkh2pqrisgM_p32O6FmA8oDvzaimvrU9zyd0vyW6HBM2BznuHLbAYUMGp5oYgEHCxmZTWDs67Jt5AGulfn-LrcewCQi89wrb00ZvP69YdjwBe-7aoXBG4_zNMZ7ecLgd8WzUqBGGtVvUhCTVSBBi85mNMSCcgYHt__PFefRHZE09nHnEX25w6iR0ZZlQxuESBkuqTcs8qjUhs2Guin1xBMSWRINj4JDdCjIVHV4hdSjrINgFU-VF1sYFRibWcboYlXifROOxCF50MGtIBkcf7dnqsrR8HEXgZLnCyikhhlQAFoh2hsj4lPWNpWum-dBWj-B0b8P-hRmermDzcPqA==
'''
encrypted = line.decode('base64')
decrypted = rsa.decrypt(encrypted, priv_key)
print decrypted
```

Can anybody can help me to convert golang function in Python? Or give me some info where I was wrong in my actual python code?

Comment: “Not the same” in what way? Does it throw an error?

Comment: @Ryan, rsa.pkcs1.DecryptionError: Decryption failed

Comment: Have you checked that both functions output the same private key? Your Python one might be parsing it differently.

Comment: the python library does not have an rsa module. Which library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong base64 decoder to decode your ciphertext. It's evident from the "-" and "_" characters present in your ciphertext that it was encoded using the URL-safe variant of base64. To decode this you should use the base64 module, e.g.

```
import base64

line = '''
Lyzkh2pqrisgM_p32O6FmA8oDvzaimvrU9zyd0vyW6HBM2BznuHLbAYUMGp5oYgEHCxmZTWDs67Jt5AGulfn-LrcewCQi89wrb00ZvP69YdjwBe-7aoXBG4_zNMZ7ecLgd8WzUqBGGtVvUhCTVSBBi85mNMSCcgYHt__PFefRHZE09nHnEX25w6iR0ZZlQxuESBkuqTcs8qjUhs2Guin1xBMSWRINj4JDdCjIVHV4hdSjrINgFU-VF1sYFRibWcboYlXifROOxCF50MGtIBkcf7dnqsrR8HEXgZLnCyikhhlQAFoh2hsj4lPWNpWum-dBWj-B0b8P-hRmermDzcPqA==
'''

encrypted = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(line)
print len(encrypted)
print encrypted.encode('hex')
```